# How i can put unique value in each box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I put unique value in each box?

I will put a link with example below.

Example: user click on `+`, a modal appears.
He selects a value from the `select` and submits.
Then the selected value is printed in that box where user pressed on `+`.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rmbWdY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( ".pat" ).append( $( "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus' aria-hidden='true' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'></span>"));
  $result = $('#result p');
  $("#btnsubmit").click(function() {
    $(".bl1 .glyphicon").hide();
    var text = $("#sel1 option:selected").text();
    $result.text(text);
  });
  $("input[type='radio']").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 90) {
      $result.removeClass('r45').addClass('r90');
    } else {
      $result.removeClass('r90').addClass('r45');
    }
  });
});
function readURL(event){
  var getImagePath = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
  $('.bg').css('background-image', 'url(' + getImagePath + ')');
}
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. What kind of unique value? A random string, incremental number...? And where should this go? We need a clearer description of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes sorry for this my english is kind bad ,i put an example is simple just where user click on + .The value will be submited  and print in same box where he clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I played a little with your strange grid.

To have ***unique numbers*** in each boxes, you have to remove the selected number and replace it with another.
`Math` functions are handy for it.
*Note that the number are not really unique in this solution... They are random.*

Then, to place the number in the right box, I added a `.glyphicon` (+ sign) click handler to get the element reference.
In this handler, I create a `span` to replace the + sign... In order to prepare an element, which can be rotated, to receive the selected number.

I added "horizontal" in the radio choices... checked by default.

So here is the code:
[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/JNVEYz?editors=1010)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var clickedPlus;

  $(document).on("click",".glyphicon",function(){
    clickedPlus = $(this).closest("div");
    var newSpan = $("<span>");
    clickedPlus.html(newSpan);
  });

  // When modal is close without submit
  $(".close").on("click",function(){
    clickedPlus.html( $( "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus' aria-hidden='true' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'></span>") );
  });

  $( ".pat" ).append( $( "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus' aria-hidden='true' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'></span>"));

  $result = $('#result p');

  $("#btnsubmit").click(function() {
    $(".bl1 .glyphicon").hide();
    var text = $("#sel1 option:selected").text();
    $("#sel1 option:selected").text(Math.round(Math.random()*10000));
    //$result.text(text);
    clickedPlus.find("span").text(text);
  });

  $("input[type='radio']").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 90) {
      //$result.removeClass('r45').addClass('r90');
      clickedPlus.find("span").removeClass('r45').addClass('r90');
    } else if ($(this).val() == 45) {
      //$result.removeClass('r90').addClass('r45');
      clickedPlus.find("span").removeClass('r90').addClass('r45');
    } else{
      clickedPlus.find("span").removeClass('r90').removeClass('r45');
    }
  });
});   // ready


function readURL(event){
  var getImagePath = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
  $('.bg').css('background-image', 'url(' + getImagePath + ')');
}
```

Comment: i appreciate your help but is not working neither to close modal or maybe is something wrong with codepen

Comment: @EzraMancini see my answer

Comment: I edited for the case the modal is closed without a submit. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Get the element position in the list and append to that element the value

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".pat").append($("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus' ></span><span class='text'></span>"));//add a span with the class .text
  $(".pat:not(.bl1)").click(function() {
    var ind = $(this).index();//get the column position
    var vind = $(this).parent().attr('class'); get the row class

    $('#myModal').attr('data-ind', ind).attr('data-vind', vind).modal('show');//pass the values to the modal window
  })
  $result = $('#result p');
  $("#btnsubmit").click(function() {
    var ind = $(this).closest('.modal').attr('data-ind');//get the values
    var vind = $(this).closest('.modal').attr('data-vind');

    var text = $("#sel1 option:selected").text();
    $result = $('.' + vind).find('.pat').eq(ind);//select the right element from the list
    $result.find(".glyphicon").hide();
     $result.find('.text').text(text);
  });
    $("input[type='radio']").change(function() {
     var ind = $(this).closest(".modal").attr("data-ind");
     var vind = $(this).closest(".modal").attr("data-vind");
     $result = $("." + vind).find(".pat").eq(ind);
     if ($(this).val() == 90) {
       $result.find('.text').removeClass("r45").addClass("r90");
     } else {
       $result.find('.text').removeClass("r90").addClass("r45");
     }
  });

});

function readURL(event) {
  var getImagePath = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
  $('.bg').css('background-image', 'url(' + getImagePath + ')');
}
```

demo:https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EmJZrY

Comment: Thank you for solution but i rotating entired div include borders and is looks weird, we can move only value printed in a paragraph?

Comment: @EzraMancini no you need to wrap you text into something then rotate it, the main question is answered, if you have other question post them in a new question

Comment: Thank you very much!! sry guys i am new in jquery:( have a nice day!!